# How to assign elements of a dictionary to JSON object in Vapor 3?

Tags: swift, vapor

In Vapor 1.5 I used to assign the elements of an existing dictionary to a JSON object as shown below. How can I do this Vapor 3?

```
 func makeCustomJSON(jsonFromReading: JSON, clientData: DataFromClient) throws -> JSON{

    var dictionaryOfStrings = [String:String]()

    dictionaryOfStrings["ChangesMadeBy"] = "Cleaner"
    dictionaryOfStrings["BookingNumber"] = clientData.bookingNumber
    dictionaryOfStrings["Claimed"] = "false"
     //some 50 properties more...


    //object read from /Users
    var finalJsonObj = jsonFromReading

    //assign the values of dictionaryOfStrings to finalJsonObj
    for i in dictionaryOfStrings {
        let key  = i.key
        let value = i.value
        finalJsonObj[key] = try JSON(node:value)
    }

    //make json from object under CancelledBy and assign it to arrayOfTimeStampObjs
    var arrayOfTimeStampObjs = try jsonFromReading["CancelledBy"]?.makeJSON() ?? JSON(node:[String:Node]())


    //assign dictionaryOfStrings to current time stamp when booking is claimed
    arrayOfTimeStampObjs[clientData.timeStampBookingCancelledByCleaner] = try JSON(node:dictionaryOfStrings)
    finalJsonObj["CancelledBy"] = arrayOfTimeStampObjs

    return finalJsonObj

} //end of makeCustomJSON
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically, JSON serialization in swift. Decoding the JSON object to a Dictionary and then modifying the dictionary and creating a new JSON.

```swift
router.get("test") { req -> String in

    let jsonDic = ["name":"Alan"]
    let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonDic, options: .prettyPrinted)
    let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    return jsonString ?? "FAILED"
}

router.get("test2") { req -> String in
    do {
        // Loading existing JSON
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:8080/test") else {
            return "Invalid URL"
        }

        let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        guard var jsonDic = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String:String] else {
            return "JSONSerialization Failed"
        }

        // Apply Changes
        jsonDic["name"] = "John"

        // Creating new JSON object
        let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonDic, options: .prettyPrinted)
        let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        return jsonString ?? "FAILED"
    }catch{
        return "ERROR"
    }
}
```

I strongly recommend to create struct or class for your data type. It would be much safer in casting using the `codable` protocol and much easier to convert between JSON and your objects type because of the `content` protocol in vapor version 3.

Comment: I would create class or struct, but the problem is that I don't know how the JSON object will look like.  Without using Codable protocol, how could I get the value of CancelledBy key and convert it to JSON?     `var arrayOfTimeStampObjs = try jsonFromReading["CancelledBy"]?.makeJSON() ?? JSON(node:[String:Node]())`